# HTML page submit sends to wrong controller method

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

I have a web application that uses the Spring Model-View-Controller architecture.  The web pages (views) are written using HTML5 with javascript and jquery scripts.  The code for the page model and controller are Java.  The page has a Calculate button that, when clicked, submits to the calculation routine of the controller which loads up objects with the inputs on the page and previous pages, does a calculation using that data, and displays the result on the page.  There is a display link, which, when clicked, will go to the display method of the page controller to make a formatted PDF page with the inputted and calculated data in it.  The display link does not appear and is not active until calculate is finished.  My problem is that when I click Calculate, then click Display, change an input on the page, and reclick Calculate, the form submits to the display method of the controller instead of the calculation method, causing a duplicate PDF with the old calculated data in it.  I have breakpoints in the java and javascript, but I can't trace the submit is following to go to the wrong method.  Can someone look at my code below and give me some advice as to how to get this to work such that the second time the Calculate button is clicked, the calculation method is invoked instead of the PDF generator method?  Thank you.

HTML page (view):

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE; chrome=1"
    http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    http-equiv="Cache-Control">
<meta content="no-cache" http-equiv="Pragma">
<meta content="0" http-equiv="Expires">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body onload="noBack();restorePage();" onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onunload="">
    <form:form method="post" name="calcform" id="calcForm"
        commandName="calcModel" action="calculateAmount.htm">
        <div id="amounts" class="containerauto" style="height: 500px;">
            <table cellspacing="10">
                <tr>
                    <td>Choose Amount1 or Amount2:<span style="color: red"> *</span></td>
                    <td style="padding-left: 5px; padding-top: 0px; width: 125px;">
                        <form:radiobutton
                            style="align:right;" path="amount1OrAmount2Radio" id="amount1Radio"
                            name="asRadio" label="Amount1Radio" required="required"
                            value="amount1RadioValue" /> 
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-top: 0px; width: 125px;">                        
                        <form:radiobutton
                            align="right" path="amount1OrAmount2Radio" id="amount2Radio" name="asRadio"
                            label="Amount2Radio" required="required" value="amount2RadioValue" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="amount1">Amount1:<span style="color: red"> *</span></label></td>
                    <td><form:input id="amount1" name="amount1"
                            path="amount1" type="text" class="form-control NumBox"
                            cssClass="txtbox"  required="required" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <form:input path="amount1Error" id="amount1Error" name="amount1Error" 
                                style="color:red; border:0; display:block;" size="122" readonly="true"></form:input>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="amount2">Amount2:<span style="color: red"> *</span></label></td>
                    <td><form:input id="amount2" name="amount2" maxlength="10" minlength="7"
                            path="amount2" type="text" min="50000" max="1000000"
                            cssClass="txtbox" required="required" onblur="validateAmount2()" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p id="amount2Error" style="font-size:12px; color:red"> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="pctMarkUp">Percent MarkUp:<span style="color: red"> *</span></label></td>
                    <td><form:select id="pctMarkUp" name="pctMarkUp" path="pctMarkUp"
                            items="${pctMarkUpList}" cssClass="dropdown" required="required" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="duration">Duration:<span style="color: red"> *</span></label></td>
                    <td><form:select id="duration" name="duration"
                            path="duration" items="${durationList}"
                            cssClass="dropdown" required="required" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td width="100%" align="center" style="width: 978px;">
                        <input type="submit" id="calculateButton" value="Calculate" class="gen-button gen-yellow">
                    </td>                   
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="calculatedAmountInfo" class="containerauto" style="height: 300px;">
            <table style="width: 950px;" style="padding:0;" style="border:0;"
                style="align:left;" id="tab3">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="padding-left: 3px">
                            <h4 style="font-size: 20px">
                                Calculated Amount
                                <hr size="3" style="margin-left: 0px">
                            </h4>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>                    
            <table align="center" cellspacing="25">
                <tr>
                    <td id="calcWaitSpinner" align="center" style="text-align:center; padding: 0; margin:0 auto;" ></td>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center" style="font-size:18px;">
                        <span id="calcWaitMessage" style="color: red">Calculating...</span>
                        <label id="calculatedAmount1Label">Calculated Amount 1: 
                            <form:input path="calculatedAmount1" id="calculatedAmount1" name="calculatedAmount1" 
                             style="font-size:18px; border:0;" readonly="true"></form:input>
                        </label>
                        <label id="calculatedAmount2Label">Calculated Amount 2: 
                            <form:input path="calculatedAmount2" id="calculatedAmount2" name="calculatedAmount2" 
                             style="font-size:18px; border:0;" readonly="true"></form:input>
                        </label>
                        <form:input path="errorMessage0" id="errorMessage0" name="errorMessage0" 
                                style="font-size:18px; color:red; border:0; display:block;" size="120" readonly="true"></form:input>
                    </td>
                </tr>                       
            </table>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td width="100%" align="center" style="width: 978px;">
                    <a id="PDFButton" class="gen-button gen-yellow" href="javascript:submitAction('PDFgenerate.htm');">Display PDF</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form:form>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/jsfolder/js/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
<script src="/jsfolder/js/jquery.ui.datepicker.validation.js"></script>
<script src="/jsfolder/js/civem.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/jsfolder/js/jquery.maskMoney.js"></script>
<script src="/jsfolder/js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/jsfolder/js/date.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/jsfolder/js/validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#amount1Radio').click(function() {
            $('#amount1').removeAttr("disabled");
            $('#amount2').val("");
            $('#amount2').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $('#amount2Error').text("");
        });
        $('#amount2Radio').click(function() {
            $('#amount2').removeAttr("disabled")
            $('#amount1').val("");
            $('#amount1').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $('#amount1Error').val("");         
        });
    });
    $(function() {
        $('#amount1').maskMoney({
            prefix : '$',
            precision : 0
        });
        $('#amount2').maskMoney({
            prefix : '$',
            precision : 0
        });
    });
     $(function() {
            // This example uses the rel attribute for the tooltip selectors.
            // The tooltip function will use the data attributes to fill in the tooltip content.
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();         
    });     
     $(function() {
            $('#calcForm').submit(function() {
                return validatePageOnCalculate();
            });
    });     
    function submitAction(actionname) {
        if(actionname == "PDFgenerate.htm"){
            document.forms[0].target = '_blank';
        }
        else{
            document.forms[0].target = '';
        }               
        document.forms[0].method = "POST";
        document.forms[0].action = actionname;
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }    
     window.history.forward();
     function noBack() { 
          window.history.forward(); 
     }
    function restorePage() {
        //Restore page to status before Calculate clicked
        if (document.getElementById("amount1Radio").checked) {
            jQuery('#amount1Radio')[0].click(); 
        } else if (document.getElementById("amount2Radio").checked) {
            jQuery('#amount2Radio')[0].click(); 
        }       
        $('#calcWaitSpinner').removeClass('timer-loader');
        document.getElementById("calcWaitSpinner").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("calcWaitMessage").style.display = "none";      
        toggleErrorMessageDisplay();        
        if (toggleCalculatedAmountDisplay() == true) { 
            setPDFDisplay();
        } else { 
            setPDFNoDisplay();
        }
        $('#calculateButton').removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    function validatePageOnCalculate() {
        clearAmount1Error(); 
        clearGeneralError();
        setCalculatedAmountNoDisplay();
        setPDFNoDisplay();
        if (validateAmount2()) {
            if (validateAmount1()) {
                if (document.getElementById("amount1Radio").checked == false && document.getElementById("amount2Radio").checked == false) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    if ((document.getElementById("amount2").value == null || document.getElementById("amount2").value.trim() == "") && 
                        (document.getElementById("amount1").value == null || document.getElementById("amount1").value.trim() == "")) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        if (document.getElementById("pctMarkUp").value == null || document.getElementById("pctMarkUp").value.trim() == "") {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            if (document.getElementById("duration").value == null || document.getElementById("duration").value.trim() == "") {
                                return false;
                            } else {
                                $('#calcWaitSpinner').addClass('timer-loader');
                                document.getElementById("calcWaitSpinner").style.display = "inline";
                                document.getElementById("calcWaitMessage").style.display = "inline";
                                $('#calculateButton').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    function validateAmount2() 
    {  
        if(document.getElementById("amount2Radio").checked == true)
        {
            var amount2Text = document.getElementById('amount2').value;
            if (amount2Text != null && amount2Text.trim() != "")
            { 
                var amount2 = Number(amount2Text.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"")).toFixed(0);
                if (amount2 < 100 || amount2 > 5000000) 
                {  
                    document.getElementById("amount2Error").style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById('amount2Error').innerHTML = "Please enter an amount between $100 - $5,000,000.";
                    return false;  
                }
                else 
                {
                    document.getElementById('amount2Error').innerHTML = "";
                    document.getElementById("amount2Error").style.display = "none";
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                document.getElementById("amount2Error").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById('amount2Error').innerHTML = "Please enter an amount between $100 - $5,000,000.";
                return false;  
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById('amount2Error').innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById('amount2').innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("amount2Error").style.display = "none";
            return true;
        }
    }
    function validateAmount1() 
    {  
        if(document.getElementById("amount1Radio").checked == true)
        {
            var Amount1Text = document.getElementById('amount1').value;
            if (Amount1Text != null && Amount1Text.trim() != "")
            { 
                clearAmount1Error();
                return true;  
            }
            else 
            {
                document.getElementById("amount1Error").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById('amount1Error').value = "Please enter an amount";
                return false;  
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            clearAmount1Error();
            return true;
        }
    }
    function clearAmount1Error() {  
        document.getElementById("amount1Error").value="";
        document.getElementById("amount1Error").style.display = "none";
    }
    function clearGeneralError() {  
        document.getElementById("errorMessage0").value="";
        document.getElementById("errorMessage0").style.display = "none";
    }
    function toggleCalculatedAmountDisplay() {

        var generalError = document.getElementById("errorMessage0").value;
        var amount1Error = document.getElementById("amount1Error").value;

        if (generalError == null || generalError == "") {
            if (amount1Error == null || amount1Error == "") {
                if (document.getElementById("amount1Radio").checked) {
                    document.getElementById("calculatedAmount1Label").style.display = "inline-block";
                    document.getElementById("calculatedAmount1").style.display = "inline-block";
                    document.getElementById("calculatedAmount2").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("calculatedAmount2Label").style.display = "none";
                    return true;
                } else if (document.getElementById("amount2Radio").checked) {
                    document.getElementById("calculatedAmount2Label").style.display = "inline-block";
                    document.getElementById("calculatedAmount2").style.display = "inline-block";
                    document.getElementById("calculatedAmount1Label").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("calculatedAmount1").style.display = "none";
                    return true;
                } else {
                    setCalculatedAmountNoDisplay();
                    return false;  
                }
            } else {
                setCalculatedAmountNoDisplay();
                return false;  
            }
        } else {
            setCalculatedAmountNoDisplay();
            return false;  
        }
    }
    function toggleErrorMessageDisplay() {

        var generalError = document.getElementById("errorMessage0").value;
        var amount1Error = document.getElementById("amount1Error").value;
        var amount2Error = document.getElementById("amount2Error").value;

        if (generalError == null || generalError == "") {
            document.getElementById("errorMessage0").style.display = "none";
        } else {
            if (document.getElementById("amount1Radio").checked == false && document.getElementById("amount2Radio").checked == false) {
                document.getElementById("errorMessage0").style.display = "none";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("errorMessage0").style.display = "block";
            }
        }

        if (amount1Error == null || amount1Error == "") {
            document.getElementById("amount1Error").style.display = "none";
        } else {
            if (document.getElementById("amount2Radio").checked) {
                document.getElementById("amount1Error").style.display = "none";
            } else {                
                document.getElementById("amount1Error").style.display = "block";
            }
        }

        if (amount2Error == null || amount2Error == "") {
            document.getElementById("amount2Error").style.display = "none";
        } else {
            if (document.getElementById("amount1Radio").checked) {
                document.getElementById("amount2Error").style.display = "none";
            } else {                
                document.getElementById("amount2Error").style.display = "block";
            }
        }

    }
    function setCalculatedAmountNoDisplay() { 
        document.getElementById("calculatedAmount1Label").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("calculatedAmount2Label").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("calculatedAmount1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("calculatedAmount2").style.display = "none";
    }
    function setPDFNoDisplay() { 
        $('#PDFButton').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        document.getElementById("PDFButtonLabel").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("PDFButton").style.display = "none";
    }   
    function setPDFDisplay() { 
        document.getElementById("PDFButtonLabel").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("PDFButton").style.display = "block";
        $('#PDFButton').removeAttr("disabled");
    }   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller code (after suitable Java imports):

```
@Controller
public class CalcFormController extends BaseController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("loggingAspect")
    private LoggingAspect logger;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("AMOUNTSERVICE")
    private AmountService amountService;

    public LoggingAspect getLogger() {
        return logger;
    }

    public void setLogger(LoggingAspect logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/inputPage"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView inputPage(@Valid @ModelAttribute("priorPageModel") PriorPageModel priorPageModel,
            BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws SystemException {

        //This is the controller method to fire to display the page above (view)

        SessionHolder sessionHolder=this.getSessionHolder(request);

        PriorPageValues priorPageValues = populatePriorPageValues(priorPageModel);

        sessionHolder.setPriorPageValues(priorPageValues);

        InputPageModel inputPageModel = new InputPageModel();
        InputPageValues inputPageValues = null;

        if(sessionHolder.getInputPageValues() != null)
        {
            inputPageValues = sessionHolder.getInputPageValues();           
            inputPageModel = populateInputPageModel(inputPageValues, inputPageModel);           
        }   

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("inputPage", "inputPageModel", inputPageModel);

        return mav;     
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"calculateAmount"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView calculateAmount(@Valid @ModelAttribute("calculateAmount") CalcModel calcModel,
            BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws SystemException {
//Do Calcs here
            return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"PDFgenerate"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView pdfGenerator(@Valid @ModelAttribute("PDFgenerate") CalcModel calcModel,
            BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
//PDF generating code here
    return mav;
    }
```